# Angular styles defined in component does not apply

Tags: html, css, angular, styles

In my project when I define this style in angular component

`span.highlighted:first-of-type { background-color: pink; }`

This does not apply on HTML. But when I define the above style in `Global styles.css` file it apply on the component. I am not sure what might be the reason. How can I solve this issue?

html

```
    <table>
           <tr>
               <td [innerHTML]='dataToSave.replaceHTML' #term></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

ts

```
   checkAndReturnData(silk: PowerWin | undefined) {
   const atom = document.createElement('span');
   atom.innerHTML = this.updateHTML(silk.first_name, silk.last_name);
   this.totalOccurrences = atom.querySelectorAll('.highlighted').length;
   this.updateButtonStates(atom);
   silk.replaceHTML = atom.innerHTML;
   this.dataToSave = silk;
}


updateHTML(value: any, last_name: any): string {
  const matcher = new RegExp(last_name, 'gi');
  const matches = Array.from(new Set(value.match(matcher)));
  if (!matches || matches.length === 0) return value;
  for (const match of matches) {
    value = value.replaceAll(match, `<span class = "highlighted data-${match}">${match}</span>`);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Share your html too.

Comment: @LiuZhang I added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `::ng-deep` before your css selector.

It allows your style to be visible in the global scope, as the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) describe it;

Comment: You mean like this `::ng-deep span.highlighted:first-of-type { background-color: pink; }` ?

Comment: @TejasMehta, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of that component encapsulation, innerHTML content is not more component inside scope, so you need to use `::ng-deep` for your selector.

`table::ng-deep span.highlighted ...`

Something like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know